# How to draw layout from XML in another View's draw() method?

Tags: android, xml, canvas, layout, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my project and I have a PieChart. I need to draw a layout in the center of the piechart, but I have to draw it in the piechart itself, not on top.

So I have modified the `drawCenterText(Canvas c)` from [PieChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer) to draw an entire Layout from a XML file instead of just a text. My XML file is ConstraintLayout with autosize TextViews. The XML should be draw in the center of the piechart.

I have inflated the XML in MainActivity and passed it as a reference to the PieChart.

```
ViewGroup centerLayout = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.center_text_layout, mPieChart, false);
mPieChart.setCenterLayout(centerLayout);
```

Now when the PieChart has to draw itself, it should also draw that centerLayout in its center. The method `drawCenterLayout(Canvas canvas)` calculates where the centerLayout should be drawn. It's all fine until the drawing itself. I don't know why the children of the centerLayout root (ConstraintLayout) are not drawn.

This is a piece of the code that should draw the centerLayout , from the PieChart `drawCenterLayout(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = centerLayout.getLayoutParams();
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(params.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(params.height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

centerLayout.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
centerLayout.layout((int)boundingRect.left, (int)boundingRect.top, (int)boundingRect.right, (int)boundingRect.bottom);
centerLayout.draw(canvas);

canvas.restore();
```

This is my XML and how the center should look like, with the text hardcoded (I have colorized the background):
[image: XML]

And this is how it ends up looking
[image]

So clearly the children are not set right... What should I do? The `centerLayout.measure` method should also measure the children automatically, right?

Comment: You don't draw from xml in onDraw.  By the time that's called, all views should already have been laid out, measured, and are ready to draw.  Your problem is not understanding or following the Android framework's system for laying out and drawing views.

Comment: I just modified the method that was in PieChartRenderer that did a lot of measurements anyway. Assuming that I move the methods "measure" and "layout" to their respective places, will that change anything? I think the result will be the same, no?

Comment: instead of modifying the chart  PieChartRenderer, you could use a relativelayout as a parent and draw a custom layout between the pie chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the measure method. I had to provide the proper parameters.

```
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pieCenter.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pieCenter.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```